# asp.net mvc application and upload file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I need to build an application which accept a file posed from the client and process it and return the information to the client.

If doing using asp.net mvc structure, where to get started?

Comment: Don't mean to be rude, but try googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this post from [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx) it's what got me started back in the preview days of MVC on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="file" />`